# SAML requests keep asking login

Tags: authentication, saml, opensaml

We are using OpenSAML 2.6.1 to implement SAML authentication. After the first request, SAMLRequest, the browser is asking for the authentication, we are inputting the correct information (user and password), but the browser is asking for it again.
No errors are returned or shown to the user, or in any logs.

Comment: Can you include a sample SAML file, a screenshot of the authentication that the browser is asking for, and who/what are the identity & services providers in this case are? For example, do you own the site the user is coming from, and the site the user is heading to, both?

Comment: SAML does not define the actual Authentication, which takes places at the IdP. The IdP has to know that the user has already authenticated by creating and maintaining some sort of session. If the 'hook' into the session is implemented via cookies potentially there is an issue that the browser has to drop that cookie. You may check the HTTP trace when performing SAML based WebSSO.

Comment: Can you have a look at a HTTP trace to see if the user is sent back to the SP before being sent to IDP and asked for authentication again